# Java .nextLine() repeats line

Tags: java

Everything of my guessing game is alright, but when it gets to the part of asking the user if he/she wants to play again, it repeats the question twice. However I found out that if I change the input method from nextLine() to next(), it doesn't repeat the question. Why is that?

Here is the input and output:

```
I'm guessing a number between 1-10
What is your guess? 5
You were wrong. It was 3
Do you want to play again? (Y/N) Do you want to play again? (Y/N) n
```

Here is the code:(It is in Java)
The last do while loop block is the part where it asks the user if he/she wants to play again.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingGame 
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean keepPlaying = true;

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Guessing Game!");

        while (keepPlaying) {
            boolean validInput = true;
            int guess, number;
            String answer;

            number = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
            System.out.println("I'm guessing a number between 1-10");
            System.out.print("What is your guess? ");
            do {
                validInput = true;
                guess = input.nextInt();
                if (guess < 1 || guess > 10) {
                    validInput = false;
                    System.out.print("That is not a valid input, " +
                            "guess again: ");
                }
            } while(!validInput);
            if (guess == number)
                System.out.println("You guessed correct!");
            if (guess != number)
                System.out.println("You were wrong. It was " + number);
            do {
                validInput = true;
                System.out.print("Do you want to play again? (Y/N) ");
                answer = input.nextLine();
                if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                    keepPlaying = true;
                else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
                    keepPlaying = false;
                else
                    validInput = false;
            } while (!validInput);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to not use a `do-while`...  People tend not to use them because they are kind of unusual.  Also, try including in your question your input and the output that is produced.

Comment: What does stepping through the debugger tell you?

Comment: You have a repeat in your title.

Comment: @vulpix if there is ever a time to use a `do-while`, its when getting and verifying input, IMO.

Comment: @MrTi: You use a do-while when you need to execute a loop AT LEAST once, but you have no idea how many iterations will be needed. That's not true in this case. A while loop suffices just fine (especially given the fact all this is taking place within a while loop already)

Comment: @AndrewMartin If you are getting input, you need to get it at least once, but you may need to do it more times if the input isn't valid.  It is true that I could use a while loop for it, but then the validInput would be accessible outside the applicable scope

Comment: @MrTiBut validInput is applicable through the program, not just in that loop. Put it like this, you're right, you could use a do while and many probably would. Personally I wouldn't, but that's just me.

Comment: @vulpix i have added the input and output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `do while` loop, you don't want the `nextLine()`, you just want `next()`.

So change this:

```
answer = input.nextLine();
```

to this:

```
answer = input.next();
```

Note, as others have suggested, you could convert this to a `while` loop. The reason for this is that `do while` loops are used when you need to execute a loop at least once, but you don't know how often you need to execute it. Whilst it's certainly doable in this case, something like this would suffice:

```
System.out.println("Do you want to play again? (Y/N) ");
answer = input.next();
while (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !answer.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
    System.out.println("That is not valid input. Please enter again");
    answer = input.next();
}

if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
    keepPlaying = false;
```

The `while` loop keeps looping as long as "y" or "n" (ignoring case) isn't entered. As soon as it is, the loop ends. The `if` conditional changes the keepPlaying value if necessary, otherwise nothing happens and your outer `while` loop executes again (thus restarting the program).

**Edit: This explains WHY your original code didn't work**

I should add, the reason your original statement didn't work was because of your first `do while` loop. In it, you use:

```
guess = input.nextInt();
```

This reads the number off the line, but not the return of the line, meaning when you use:

```
answer = input.nextLine();
```

It immediately detects the leftover carriage from the `nextInt()` statement. If you don't want to use my solution of reading just `next()` you could swallow that leftover by doing this:

```
guess = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
rest of code as normal...
```

Comment: Your suggested while loop will cause an infinite loop as it stands currently.

Comment: @FGreg: Whoops! Absolutely spot on, have amended it. Thanks for that.

Comment: @AndrewMartin Thank you soooooooooo much! I really appreaciated it :D

Answer (score 5):

The problem really lies in a completely different segment of code.  When in the previous loop `guess = input.nextInt();` is executed, it leaves a newline in the input.  Then, when `answer = input.nextLine();` is executed in the second loop, there already is a newline waiting to be read and it returns an empty String, which activates the final `else` and `validInput = false;` is executed, to repeat the loop (and the question).

One solution is to add an `input.nextLine();` before the second loop.  Another is to read `guess` with `nextLine()` and then parse it into an int.  But this complicates things as the input could not be a correct `int`.  On a second thought, the code already presents this issue.  Try entering a non-numeric response.  So, define a function

```
public static int safeParseInt(String str) {
    int result;
    try {  
        result= Integer.parseInt(str) ;
    } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {  
      result= -1 ;  
    }  
    return result ;  
}
```

And then replace your first loop with:

```
do {
    validInput= true ;
    int guess= safeParseInt( input.nextLine() ) ;
    if( guess < 1 || guess > 10 ) {
        validInput= false ;
        System.out.print("That is not a valid input,  guess again: ");
    }
} while( !validInput );
```

PS:  I don't see any problem with `do-while` loops.  They are part of the language, and the syntax clearly indicates that the condition is evaluated after the body is executed at least one time.  We don't need to remove useful parts of the language (at least from practice) just because others could not know them.  On the contrary:  if we do use them, they will get better known!

Answer (score 4):

```
    validInput = false;

    do {

        System.out.print("Do you want to play again? (Y/N) ");
        answer = input.next();

        if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){

            keepPlaying = true;
            validInput = true;

        } else if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {

            keepPlaying = false;
            validInput = true;

        }        

    } while(!validInput);
```

I changed the coding style as I find this way more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `nextInt` will stop as soon as the int ends, but leaves the newline in the input buffer. To make your code correctly read the answer, you'd have to enter it on the same line as your guess, like <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>.

To make it behave more than one would expect, ignore the first `nextLine` result if it contains only whitespace, and just call `nextLine` again in that case without printing a message.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the output of `input.nextLine()` will include the newline character at the end of the line, whereas `input.next()` will not (but the `Scanner` will stay on the same line). This means the output is never equal to `"y"` or `"n"`. Try [trimming](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) the result:

```
answer = input.nextLine().trim();
```